# Datepicker with only Month and Day (Hide year)

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am unable to find any documented way to hide year on the ngx-bootstrap datepicker. I tried `dateInputFormat: 'MMDD'` but year still shows in datepicker header.
Documentation link:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker
I would like to show something like:
[image: datepicker]

Comment: There isn't any option available in the current version to hide the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the thing is use encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None and a class like

```
.bs-datepicker-head button:nth-child(3){
  display:none!important;
}
```

The problem with ViewEncapsultaion.None is that all your .css in component affect to all the application. So, better write a .css like

```
.custom .bs-datepicker-head button:nth-child(3){
  display:none!important;
}
```

So, if we use ViewEncapsultaion.None, only affect to the datepicker that has a class "custom". To create a datePicker with class custom you need use [bsConfig].

I write the code

Our .html

```
<div class="content">
  <h4>datepicker should display current date:</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [minDate]="minDate"
            [maxDate]="maxDate"
            #dp="bsDatepicker" [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
            bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="myDateValue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And our component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myDateValue: Date;
  bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDateValue = new Date();
    //see that our class was "theme-green custom"
    this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: 'theme-green custom' });
  }
}
```

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-j91pcq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [NgbDatepickerI18n](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepickerI18n) and overwrite the method `getYearNumerals` to return an empty string. In fact it's this method that is used by the NgbDatePicker to render the year on the navigation header.

Here is a simple example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class CustomDateI18n extends NgbDatepickerI18nDefault {
  getYearNumerals(year: number): string {
    return '';
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NgbDatepickerI18n,
      useClass: CustomDateI18n
    }
  ]
})
```